# Issue regarding $wpdb->prepare()

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb

$wpdb->prepare() is adding single quote ('') like below.

I am using below code

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %s ",$table_name);
echo $sql;
```

I am getting output like below

```
SELECT * FROM 'wp_nametbl'
```

But I would like to get output like below

```
SELECT * FROM wp_nametbl
```

Answer (score 1):

prepare() is used to escape the values for example in the WHERE-statement. Usually it is anticipated the table selection is "hardcoded". If you can't use for example $wpdb->posts or the other "table"-functions, you could whitelist the allowed tables and check if $table_name is on this white list:

```
<?php
    $allowed_tables = array( $wpdb->prefix . 'nametbl', $wpdb->prefix . 'nametbl2' );
    if( ! in_array( $table_name, $allowed_tables ) )
        wp_die( 'Wrong input.' );

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @websupporter. How can I use your code ?? What does `$wpdb->prefix` do ??

Comment: Hi Foysal. $wpdb->prefix sets the prefix for the WP database. Usually this is wp_ but since you can change it during the installation, $wpdb->prefix will choose the correct prefix. Since $wpdb is a global variable you need to use global $wpdb; in functions. More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb